# Query Watson Discovery Service by Document ID

Tags: service, watson, discovery

Is there a way to query by document id in WDS?  I've tried things like

- id:"9cdd3db8-b127-4176-b727-b31bf86870fc"
- id:9cdd3db8-b127-4176-b727-b31bf86870fc

Neither of these work.  I'm doing some testing, and I'd like to guarantee that I can get back a specific document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter parameter `_id:9cdd3db8-b127-4176-b727-b31bf86870fc`

[reference](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/380445/query-watson-discovery-documents-by-id/) on IBM DVW